# Fragment: Get object from activity (Tab View)

Tags: android, object, android-activity, android-fragments, tabview

how can I can access in this example the object "selectedBox" from the fragment? I need it in the main activity for testing connection and in the fragment.

In the moment I create it in the main and the fragment.

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener{

    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private ActionBar actionBar;
    private MainTabAdapter mAdapter;
    private String[] tabs = { "Live" };
    private box selectedBox;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        actionBar = getActionBar();
        mAdapter = new MainTabAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
        for (String tab_name : tabs) {
            actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tab_name).setTabListener(this));
        }

        viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
            }
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
            }
            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
            }
        });

        selectedBox = new box(this);
    }

    public void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
        if(selectedBox.getId() != -1){
            checkReachable(selectedBox.getIpPort());
        }else {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class);
            this.startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
    }

    private void checkReachable(String ipPort) {
        Log.d("XML Request", "CHECK BOX");
        String e2About = "http://" + ipPort + "/web/about";
        getXml.DownloadCompleteListener dcl = new getXml.DownloadCompleteListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDownloadComplete(String result) {
                if (!result.contains("<e2enigmaversion>")) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Active box not reachable.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SettingsActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }else{
                    viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
                }
            }
        };
        getXml downloader = new getXml(dcl);
        downloader.execute(e2About);
    }


    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        switch (id){
            case R.id.action_settings:
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

MainTabAdapter

```
public class MainTabAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public MainTabAdapter(FragmentManager fm){
        super(fm);
    }
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int index) {
        switch (index) {
            case 0:
                return new MainFragmentLive();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

MainFragmentLive.java

```
public class MainFragmentLive extends ListFragment {

    private box selectedBox;

    private List<String> bouquetListString;

    private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main_live, container, false);

        Log.d("Position", "Main Live Set Box");
        selectedBox = new box(getActivity());
        bouquetListString = selectedBox.getBouquets().get(2);
        if(bouquetListString.size() < 1){
            getBouquetBox();
        }
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, bouquetListString);
        setListAdapter(adapter);

        ImageButton reloadBouquet = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.reloadBouquet);
        reloadBouquet.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                getBouquetBox();
            }
        });

        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        return view;
    }


    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        SharedPreferences savedData = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("box",0);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = savedData.edit();
        editor.putInt("boId", position);
        editor.apply();
        Intent gotoChannels = new Intent(getActivity(), ChannelListActivity.class);
        startActivity(gotoChannels);
    }

    public void getBouquetBox(){
        getXml.DownloadCompleteListener dcl = new getXml.DownloadCompleteListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDownloadComplete(String result) {
                selectedBox.delBouquets();
                bouquetListString.clear();
                String [] tags = {"e2servicereference", "e2servicename"};
                List<List<String>> bouquetsList = parseXml.parseXmlByTag(result, tags);
                selectedBox.addBouquets(bouquetsList);
                bouquetListString.addAll(selectedBox.getBouquets().get(2));
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        };
        Log.d("XML Request", "GET BOUQUET");
        getXml downloader = new getXml(dcl);
        downloader.execute("http://" + selectedBox.getIpPort() + "/web/getservices");
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

fragment_main_live.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_margin="8dp">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.8"
            android:text="@string/selectBouquet"
            style="@style/header1"/>
        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/reloadBouquet"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_action_refresh"
            android:contentDescription="@string/search"
            android:layout_weight=".20"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"/>
    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@android:id/list" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Can we see your xml?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an interface to your activity from your fragment.  Something like:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener,MainFragment.getSelectedBox {

private ViewPager viewPager;
private ActionBar actionBar;
private MainTabAdapter mAdapter;
private String[] tabs = { "Live" };
private box selectedBox;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
....
}

//called from the MainFragment
@Override
public void AccessSelectedBox {
    this.box = <do something with box>

}

}
```

Fragment Class

```
public class MainFragment extends ListFragment {

//interface to the MainActivity activity class
  private getSelectedBox listener;

  public interface getSelectedBox {
      public void AccessSelectedBox();

  }

}
```

Here is a good article on this: http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidFragments/article.html.